# iptest3 with IPython

Tags: ipython

I'm brand new to Python programming and trying to get myself a functional base from which I can run things like the IPython Notebook which looks pretty exciting.

Thus far I have both `Python 2.7` and `3.3` from `python.org` installed in OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) as well as `ActiveTcl 8.5.13`. Almost everything that I've tried thus far works as expected. I'm focused on learning `3.3`, but want to have the option of using `2.7` too. I read up in several documents that I need to start gaining access to PyPI packages using a Python package manager and that `distribute` is the one I should use for 3k. So I installed that according to the documentation I found and it seemed to work fine.

I also installed `pip` as directed, and a number of others.

At this point, I have:

```
$ pip freeze
distribute==0.6.34
ipython==0.13.1
nose==1.2.1 (installed after IPython)
pexpect==2.4 (installed after IPython)
pyflakes3k==0.4.3
readline==6.2.4.1 (installed after IPython)
```

At this point, I'm doing this from [ipython.org guidance](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.13.1/install/install.html)

And when I did `$ easy_install pexpect`, I got a bunch of errors:

```
$ easy_install pexpect
Searching for pexpect
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pexpect/
Reading http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/
Reading http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=59762
Best match: pexpect 2.4
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pexpect/pexpect-2.4.tar.gz#md5=fe82d69be19ec96d3a6650af947d5665
Processing pexpect-2.4.tar.gz
Writing /var/folders/td/td0Sh8EfGFuMCnKex1v+q++++TI/-Tmp-/easy_install-s4dtyy/pexpect-2.4/setup.cfg
Running pexpect-2.4/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/td/td0Sh8EfGFuMCnKex1v+q++++TI/-Tmp-/easy_install-s4dtyy/pexpect-2.4/egg-dist-tmp-5h5cg4
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/fdpexpect.py", line 36
raise ExceptionPexpect, 'The fd argument is not a valid file descriptor.'
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/FSM.py", line 77
return `self.value`
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pexpect.py", line 82
except ImportError, e:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pexpect-2.4-py3.3.egg/fdpexpect.py", line 36
raise ExceptionPexpect, 'The fd argument is not a valid file descriptor.'
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pexpect-2.4-py3.3.egg/FSM.py", line 77
return `self.value`
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pexpect-2.4-py3.3.egg/pexpect.py", line 82
except ImportError, e:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Adding pexpect 2.4 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pexpect-2.4-py3.3.egg
Processing dependencies for pexpect
Finished processing dependencies for pexpect
```

That looks bad to me (although I don't yet have the expertise to really interpret it), and so I'm not sure if I have a complete install of `pexpect`.

After installing `nose` (before `pexpect` as per URL above), I tried running `iptest` and `iptest3` from the command line, and both failed to find the command, but after I did `easy_install ipython` again (after `nose`), I noticed that this install added `iptest3` (as well as `ipcluster3` and a few other scripts) to my path, and now my bash shell *can* find iptest3, but when I run it, I get some more bad-looking output:

```
$ iptest3
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/iptest3", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('ipython==0.13.1', 'console_scripts', 'iptest3')()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py3.3.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 343, in load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py3.3.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2308, in load_entry_point
return ep.load()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py3.3.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2014, in load
entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
from .config.loader import Config
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/IPython/config/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
from .application import *
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 31, in <module>
from IPython.config.configurable import SingletonConfigurable
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/IPython/config/configurable.py", line 26, in <module>
from .loader import Config
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/IPython/config/loader.py", line 27, in <module>
from IPython.utils.path import filefind, get_ipython_dir
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/IPython/utils/path.py", line 25, in <module>
from IPython.utils.process import system
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/IPython/utils/process.py", line 27, in <module>
from ._process_posix import _find_cmd, system, getoutput, arg_split
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/IPython/utils/_process_posix.py", line 22, in <module>
from IPython.external import pexpect
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/IPython/external/pexpect/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
import pexpect
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pexpect-2.4-py3.3.egg/pexpect.py", line 82
except ImportError, e:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

After doing all that, I noted that my `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current` had been pointing to `2.7`, and I guessed that that might be related to my problems and changed the symbolic link to point to `3.3`, but `iptest3` still fails with the error above.

Any other thoughts on what to do to fix this? It's clear that `iptest` is pretty important to doing anything else (like `IPython Notebook`) I want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a py3-compatible fork of pexpect called [pexpect-u](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect-u) (the u is for unicode, the main difference between the two).  You need this to run the pexpect-based parts of IPython on Python 3.
Should be a simple

```
pip install pexpect-u
```

side note: pexpect-u is by IPython developer Thomas Kluyver, who did most of the heavy lifting bringing py3 compatibility to IPython.

Comment: Many thanks. `pip install pexpect-u` seemed to work without complaints, and now `iptest3` also seems to work fine. Is there some kind of guide that I should be reading for IPython and py3 (other than [this](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.13.1/install/install.html) which tells me to use pexpect rather than pexpect-u) that would give me these kinds of insights you offer here before I go asking what was probably a trivial question to most folks here?